# How to play YouTube video in background in mobile software? -Any chance to getting permission?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I know it is not allowed to do so, but I find many apps in app store or google play have this feature. **Is there any paid service for developers to do this?** I don't know whether these apps have business cooperation with YouTube.

Comment: Do you mean play the video in background or just the audio playing in the background?

Comment: I mean the app can keep playing video when users go to other apps or with screen off.Any suggestion?